# How to use the output of a BAT file as a variable in it's parent

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

( Different from [Batch file include external file for variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763875/batch-file-include-external-file-for-variables) )

What I'm trying to do is read a batch file, from another batch file. The parent batch file calls upon the child batch file to retrieve a variable from an INI file (the childs sole purpose). It then echos the returned value, and exits. What I want is for the parent batch to pick up this output and use it as a variable for its own operations.

So to clarify: I'm not setting a value in the child process, and would prefer if I didn't have to, because this child process is called twice, to do the same operation twice, but to retrieve different values.

Answer (score 1):

the usual way to get a command's output is a `for`construct:

b.bat

```
@echo hello
```

a.bat:

```
for /f %%i in ('b.bat') do set output=%%i
echo %output%
```